# How to insert at a "level" of a dict/list data-structure? - { 'foo': 'bar', 'more': [ { 'foo': None } ] }

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, traversal

I have a simple data-structure, roughly the following, with arbitrary depth:

```
# Level 0
{ 'foo': 'bar', 'more': 
  [   # Level 1
      { 'foo': 'can', 'more': [    # Level 2
                                   { 'foo': 'haz', 'more': [] }
                              ]
      },
      { 'foo': 'baz', 'more': [    # Level 2
                                   { 'foo': None, 'more': [] }
                              ]
      }
  ]
}
```

Working on a function to insert at a certain level. If `foo` value is `None`, then insert `value`, else insert a new 'sibling', i.e., a new `dict` at the same level. Apart from the 0th level, everything is within a `list`, so should be `append`able.

---

Attempt:

```
def traverse_to_level(obj, level):
    if obj['_level'] == level:
        return obj

    for _obj in obj['block']:
        found = traverse_to_level(_obj, level)
        if found is not None:
            return found

    return None


def set_obj(top_obj, value, level):
    obj = traverse_to_level(top_obj, level)
    if obj is None:
        directive = traverse_to_level(top_obj, level - 1)
    assert obj is not None
    if obj['foo'] is None:
        obj['foo'] = value
    elif obj['_level'] < level:
        obj['more'].append({'foo': value, 'more': [], '_level': level})
    else:
        obj = traverse_to_level(top_obj, level - 1)
        obj['more'].append({'foo': value, 'more': [], '_level': level})

    return obj
```

---

**What's the right way to traverse a structure like this, and update it in-place by `level`?**

---

EDIT: Another example, showing more than just 'foo' on each object. To simplify things, if the input startswith `#` then it's the input should be added to `alpha`, otherwise `beta`. If either are already filled, then insert adjacent (i.e., a new sibling `{'alpha': None, 'beta': None, 'more': []}`).

```
def make_ab(alpha=None, beta=None, more=None):
    return {
        'alpha': alpha,
        'beta': beta,
        'more': more or []
    }


def parse(arguments):
    level, last_level_change, top_d = 0, -1, make_ab()

    for idx, arg in enumerate(arguments):
        if arg == '#{':
            level += 1
        elif arg in frozenset(('#d', '##dog')):
            level += 1
            last_level_change = idx
        elif arg == '#}':
            level -= 1
        elif idx == last_level_change - 1:
            set_obj(top_d, arg, level, 'alpha')
        elif idx == last_level_change - 2:
            set_obj(top_d, arg, level, 'beta')
        else:
            set_obj(top_d, arg, level,
                    'beta' if arg.startswith('##')
                    else 'alpha')
    return top_d
```

Usage, hinting as to the expected hierarchy through indentation:

```
actual = parse(
    ('#d',
        'definite',
        '##foo_alpha_5', 'nice_beta',
        '##name_2', 'amazing_beta',
        '##dog',
          '##fancy_name', 'fancy_BETA_f',
          '##one_AL_PHA_of', 'I_C_U_B_ETA',
        '#}',
    '#}')
)
```

And this is the output expected:

```
{
    'alpha': 'definite',
    'beta': None,
    'more': [
        {
            'alpha': '##foo_alpha_5',
            'beta': 'nice_beta',
            'more': []
        },
        {
            'alpha': '##name_2',
            'beta': 'amazing_beta',
            'more': [
                {
                    'alpha': '##fancy_name',
                    'beta': 'fancy_BETA_f',
                    'more': []
                },
                {
                    'alpha': '##one_AL_PHA_of',
                    'beta': 'I_C_U_B_ETA',
                    'more': []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you are asking. Are you starting with the nested dicts in the first code block and want to add a `level` property to each nested dict? Or are you starting with some other data and trying to create the nested dicts from that? The business about `If foo value is None, then insert value` makes it confusing.

Comment: The goal is to: update the `foo` value at the right `level` if it's `None`, else insert a new `dict` as a sibling to the current `dict`, and set its value accordingly. If nothing exists at that level, then a `mkdir -p` style solution would be in order. @MarkMeyer does that make sense?

Comment: what if the level is 5 and you have only level  2? you are creating  new levels till level 5 or you create a new dict sibling at level 2 ? can you show your expected output

Comment: The way I've implemented this means that it'll never need to go more than 1 level deeper than what exists in order to create a new `['foo','more']` `dict`. But yes, to take your example, you would need to create new 'children', grandchildren &etc. until you reach 5 deep. To simplify ontology, rename `more` to `children`.

Comment: Maybe, you can write some tests first? Starting with what should happen with `{}` when you add `foo` and upto some more involved structure. If anything, maybe then you understand what the function needs to do and how. Right now it is hard to understand your `level` logic.

Comment: Please update your question with sample input parameters to your function and the corresponding expected output. As it stands there are too many ways to interpret your question.

Comment: I've now added a bigger example. Along with expected input and output. Also replied to all—3 [currently]—answers with full compiling attempts at using their algorithms to solve this.

Comment: @AT It seems that your example misses some `#{`. And you didn't explain how to reach to deeper levels. All you explained so far is when to insert into alpha and when into beta and how to create siblings. How do get new levels? Also in your example I can't follow how you get the expected result. For me it looks like: 1st argument `#d` --> fill `alpha='#d'` (since startswith #), then 2nd argument `definite` --> fill `beta='definite'` since doesn't start with `#`. However you end up with `alpha='definite', beta=None`. How is that possible according to your explanation?

Comment: There are two ways to ascend levels in the hierarchy: `#{` and with `#d` or `##dog`. So that's why `definite` has no `beta`, and why `##foo_alpha_5` is an `alpha` one level deeper.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
def set_obj(top_obj, value, level):
    if level == 1:
        more = top_obj['more']
        hasnt_none = True
        for n in more:
            if n['foo'] is None:
                n['foo'] = value
                hasnt_none = False
        if hasnt_none:
            more.append({'foo': value, 'more': []})
    else:
        for n in top_obj['more']:
            set_obj(n, value, level-1)
```

? Test:

```
from pprint import pprint
set_obj(data, 'VALUE', 2)
pprint(data)
```

Output:

```
{'foo': 'bar',
 'more': [{'foo': 'can',
           'more': [{'foo': 'haz', 'more': []}, {'foo': 'VALUE', 'more': []}]},
          {'foo': 'baz', 'more': [{'foo': 'VALUE', 'more': []}]}]}
```

If the more of the level contains one or more `{'foo': None, ...}` elements, then update the value of these elements. Else, just append `{'foo': value, 'more': []}` element.

Comment: Thanks but I couldn't get this to work properly, attempt (runs, and includes expected output): https://ideone.com/SxABz4

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with nested lists you also need to specify the index at each level in order to form some kind of path. As you indicate in your example there are two different lists at level 2, so at level 1 you need to choose between the first or second dict. For that you can use a path in form of a list or tuple: for example `(1, 0)` means at level 1 select the second dict and at level 2 select the first dict. This can be written as a function:

```
from functools import reduce

def get_nested_dict(obj, path):
    return reduce(lambda o, n: o['more'][n], path, obj)
```

Then testing it on the example data:

```
print(get_nested_dict(test_obj, (0, 0)))  # foo: haz
print(get_nested_dict(test_obj, (1, 0)))  # foo: None
```

Now for the insertion we need to get the wrapping list so we can insert a sibling dict in case the `'foo'` key is already occupied. For that we can slightly modify the above function:

```
def get_nested_list(obj, path):  # assert len(path) > 0
    return reduce(lambda o, n: o[n]['more'], path, obj['more'])
```

Then we can build the insertion function on top of that:

```
def insert_into(obj, path, value):
    lst = get_nested_list(obj, path[:-1])
    try:
        dct = lst[path[-1]]
    except IndexError:
        lst.append({'foo': value, 'more': []})  # create new dict
    else:
        if dct['foo'] is None:
            dct['foo'] = value
        else:
            lst.append({'foo': value, 'more': []})  # create new dict
```

We can test it on the example data:

```
pprint(test_obj, sort_dicts=False)
insert_into(test_obj, (0, 0), 'new')
pprint(test_obj, sort_dicts=False)
insert_into(test_obj, (1, 0), 'new')
pprint(test_obj, sort_dicts=False)
```

Which prints the following:

```
{'foo': 'bar',
 'more': [{'foo': 'can', 'more': [{'foo': 'haz', 'more': []}]},
          {'foo': 'baz', 'more': [{'foo': None, 'more': []}]}]}
{'foo': 'bar',
 'more': [{'foo': 'can',
           'more': [{'foo': 'haz', 'more': []}, {'foo': 'new', 'more': []}]},
          {'foo': 'baz', 'more': [{'foo': None, 'more': []}]}]}
{'foo': 'bar',
 'more': [{'foo': 'can',
           'more': [{'foo': 'haz', 'more': []}, {'foo': 'new', 'more': []}]},
          {'foo': 'baz', 'more': [{'foo': 'new', 'more': []}]}]}
```

Comment: I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong here -> https://ideone.com/Q6FlUU - All I'm getting is `list index out of range` errors… I've tried `path` values of `(level, 0)`, `(0, level)`, `(level, -1)`, `(-1, level)`.

Comment: @AT Each element in the `path` object is the index for the corresponding level. I.e. the first `path` element corresponds to the index at level 1, the second element to level 2 and so on: `path = (<index_lvl_1>, <index_lvl_2>, ...)`. So the level at which the value will be inserted is `len(path)` but that alone doesn't uniquely identify the corresponding object (hence `path` is used). So for example `(0, -1)` means at level 1 take the first element and then at level 2 take the last element.

Comment: Okay, but then why aren't any of my example attempts working?

Comment: @AT I guess because you supplied `level == 2` but none of the levels has 3 objects. Instead of increasing or decreasing `level` you need to build the path leading to the objects instead. For example if you always want to consider the last element you can do `path = []` and then instead of `level += 1` you do `path.append(-1)` and instead of `level -=1` you do `path.pop(-1)`.

Comment: That still gives me a `IndexError: list index out of range` error. https://ideone.com/5BzYCY

Comment: @AT I see, since you're building the structure incrementally it can be that no dict is available yet, hence the `IndexError`. I modified the `insert_into` function to deal with that case. Now it runs your example code without error. However the result is different from your `expect` but according to the rules you gave in your question and comments it makes sense. You start with a dict object `top_d` and the first `arg` you parse is `#d` so it means descend one level into `top_d['more']`. Hence the consecutive `definite` will end up in level 1 not level 0 as you indicated in `expect`.

Comment: @AT By the way, right now you can only insert data into level 1 or deeper. If you want to insert data into `top_d` alpha or beta key you need to make a little modification. Namely you need to wrap `top_d` into a list before parsing like: `top_d = [top_d]` and then unwrap after parsing has finished: `top_d = top_d[0]`. If your parsed data is correct this artificial list will not be populated any further, it just exists to make the data structure symmetric from the perspective of the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm ready to accept your answer. There is some duplication though, so just add a `return` after `lst.append(dct)`… https://ideone.com/J4sSFV

Comment: @AT Indeed thanks for the pointer. I meant to create an empty dict instead like in our example by the `make_ab` function. Then you don't need a return. I modified the answer. Using `return` also works though. Whatever you think reads nicer (using return probably has better performance in case that matters). Looking at it again, I think using a separate `else` branch is nicer, so I will adapt it.